# JSON attribute value split by space and put them into new attributes using Jolt transform Apache nifi

Tags: json, split, apache-nifi, jolt

I have json object as following,

```
{
    "sensorId":2,
    "dataValue":26.7, 
    "dateTime":"2020:12:29 14:20:31"
}
```

I want to convert it to the following,

```
{
    "sensorId":2,
    "dataValue":26.7, 
    "date":"2020:12:29",
    "time":"14:20:31"
}
```

Using Apache nifi Jolt transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can split with space ("* *") and assign splitted parts.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "sensorId": "sensorId",
      "dataValue": "dataValue",
      "dateTime": {
        "* *": {
          "$(0,1)": "date",
          "$(0,2)": "time"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```